# Change the value of the key in custom array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, arrays

Click on the either ASC or DESC link for fieldname and create an key:value pair object and push it to an array; 
If key exists replace the value with click event selected and updated the arrays key:value;

Example

Click Sort By Name - DESC:

```
[{"name":"desc"}]
```

Again Click Sort By Name - ASC:

```
[{"name":"asc"}]
```

Click Sort By Age - DESC:

```
[{"name":"asc"},{"age":"desc"}]
```

Again Click Sort By Name - DESC:

```
[{"name":"desc"},{"age":"desc"} ]
```

[DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/sgZz3zSKOmK8RuuiSGwu?p=preview)

```
$scope.clickME = function(fieldName, orderType) {

    var obj = {};
    obj[fieldName] = orderType;

    updateArray($scope.sortList, obj);

  }

 var updateArray = function(array, newObject) {
  //console.log(newObject);
  var hash = {};
  var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        hash = array[i];
        console.log(array[i]);
        console.log(hash.hasOwnProperty(newObject));
        //How to check the key is same? not the value as am passing same key but value are different
        if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(newObject)) {

        //check for the value and replace it 
        //    object[fieldName] = (newObject[fieldName] === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        //    return;
        }
    }
    array.push(newObject);
};
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Find the custom fieldname(name, age or gender) in the array and replace its value to either 'asc' or 'desc';

Comment: What array? There's no array in the code you posted. Code should be posted **on this site** and not linked from elsewhere.

Comment: @Pointy : Had shared the DEMO link where the actual functionality exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the jquery extend method. It takes two objects and adds the new to the original and replaces the original.

```
$scope.clickMe = function(fieldName, orderType)
{
    var obj = {};
    obj[fieldName] = orderType;
    $.extend($scope.sortList, obj);
}
```

Since you are already casting them both to an object, you do just use extend directly.

if you want to use the strings and not do the cast you can do this.

```
$scope.sortList[fieldName] = orderType;
```

it will replace the value if it is there, and add a new one if it isn't

Comment: Key is the fieldname passed as a parameter with click event which can be either ASC or DESC;  For Example:  Sort By Name:<a href="#" ng-click="clickME('name','asc')">asc</a> <a href="#" ng-click="clickME('name','desc')">desc</a>

Comment: changed to show how to use it with values, and how to avoid the cast since it will always be a single key value pair